Unable to integrate milvus to spring boot application
I am trying to integrate Milvus with my Spring Boot Application but I am getting status 500: Internal Server error as soon as I create a milvus client.
This is the code I am writing :
String CLUSTER_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:19530/";
ConnectConfig connectConfig = ConnectConfig.builder().uri(CLUSTER_ENDPOINT).build();
MilvusClientV2 client = new MilvusClientV2(connectConfig);


Can anyone help me with this error?
